# can we create two columns with same name in database?

Tags: sql

Just want to ask can we create two columns with same name in database table..

Please check the screenshot below i want 2 columns with same name that is driver age Or is there any other way to put both values in same columns some thing like 21-24 , 25+ or any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create two columns with **exactly** the same name. Because if that was possible, how would SQL know in what column you want to insert values (keep in mind that you can insert values by the order you determine, for example both would work:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (x, y);
INSERT INTO tbl (col2, col1) VALUES (y, x);
```

). But you can name them slightly different, like `col1` and `col_1`, like in your example. Then everything will work fine.

Comment: What about column names with similar spelling but different cases? E.g., `COL` and `col` - is that variation allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You never told us which database you were using, but most likely your RDBMS will not allow creating a table with two or more columns having the same name.  However, when querying a result set you should be able to give the same *alias* to two different columns, e.g.

```
SELECT
    driverage AS age,
    driver_age AS age
    ...
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Do i need to put this in my SQL file

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I have given you a way to query out the same column name/alias.  Your create table script obviously cannot do this.