# Can we create two columns with same name but different case in database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Can we create two (or more) columns in Postgres/ MySQL with the same name but a different case? As in does case-sensitivity matter in column names?

For e.g., Can a table contain two columns with names - `COL` and `col`?

Linked post: [can we create two columns with same name in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129072/can-we-create-two-columns-with-same-name-in-database) only talks about same names, but not about case sensitivity.

Comment: Find a better name. In your example non of the column names matches the age of the driver. That makes it a bad name. Both represent some range and/or category. A better name avoids your problem and gives you a better datamodel. Especially when you use a range data type.

Comment: Have a look at this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we create two (or more) columns in Postgres/ MySQL with the same
> name but a different case? As in does case-sensitivity matter in
> column names?

Not possible to create columns with same name - yes case-sensitivity matters.

Example in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id int,
  id int
 );
 
 CREATE TABLE test1(
  id int,
  ID int
 );
```

Output in MySQL:

```
Schema Error: Error: ER_DUP_FIELDNAME: Duplicate column name 'id'
```

Output in PostgreSQL:

```
Schema Error: error: column "id" specified more than once
```

SELECT statement:

```
 SELECT 
     id as "id",
     ID1 as "id"
 FROM test;
```

Output:

```
id
2
```

Case-sensitive SELECT:

```
 SELECT 
     id as "id",
     ID1 as "ID"
 FROM test;
```

Output:

```
id  ID
1   2
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, quoted identifiers are case sensitive and Postgres [follows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) that standard.

So the following:

```
select column_one as "COL",
       column_two as "col"
from ...
```

Or as part of a table

```
create table dont_do_this
(
   "COL" integer,
   "col" integer
);
```

Those are two different names as they become case sensitive due to the use of the double quotes.

But I would strongly advise to **not** do that. This will most probably create confusion and problems down the line.

---

I *think* this should work with MySQL as well, but as it traditionally doesn't care about following the SQL standard, I don't know.

Comment: Nice answer! You may want to update the mysql part with information from the relevant section in mysql manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html